# how to setup Confluent Kafka Schema Registry in Cluster mode

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Setup :- We have 3 Schema registry instance behind AWS ELB. how to change the schema_registry.properties file to setup schema registry in cluster mode?

We are calling schema registry with ELB endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The cluster of Schema Registry instances will be established by each instance contacting the same ZooKeeper cluster, so you'll want to basically have each instance have the same configuration. A single master will be elected using the strategy [in the docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/design.html#single-master-architecture) and any follower that receives a write request will just forward that request to the leader. If for some reason you only want certain instances to be master eligible, you can set `master.eligbility=false` in your properties file. If you want to get fancy and set non-default advertised listeners for your instances, then those have to be unique per instance (they are host:port combinations so this should be expected).

Comment: All of my instances are connecting to same zookeeper instance. To test what I did was 
(1) I am registering schema by hitting ELB and checking which machine actually received that request...
(2) Then I am stoping the service in  that instance behind elb
(3) Then try to get the schema by hitting ELB but other instances not able to process that request (getting schema not found error.)

this means the schema details are not shared by other SR instances. Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: Something else must be here that's missing then. Maybe you can post your current config for all 3 instances?